# Dimension of output in Dense layer Keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I have the sample following model

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
sample_model = models.Sequential()
sample_model.add(layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(4,)))
sample_model.add(layers.Dense(16, input_shape = (44,)))

sample_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

IP for the model:

```
sam_x = np.random.rand(10,4)
sam_y = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,])
sample_model.fit(sam_x,sam_y)
```

The confusion is the `fit` should have thrown an error of `shape mismatch` as the `input_shape` for the `2nd Dense Layer` is given as `(None,44)` but the `output` for the `1st Dense Layer` (which is the input of the `2nd Dense Layer`) will be of shape `(None,32)`. But it ran successfully.

I dont understand `why there was no error`. Any clarifications will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found by just printing

```py
sample_model.summary()
```

giving

```bash
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 32)                160       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 16)                528       
=================================================================
Total params: 688
Trainable params: 688
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Indeed, the `input_shape` argument in a layer that is not the first one is ignored in a Sequential model.